# How can I exclude a file in a folder from basic auth (regex help)?

Tags: apache-2.2, regex

I have a folder on my site which contains admin files and I've added basic auth following a little unwanted attention.  This works fine however a couple of the admin functions won't work through basic auth as they handle file uploads and so I want to exclude these files from the auth.  It shouldn't have any security implications as any rogue user wouldn't be able to access the pages that could create a session to use these functions.

I am using the following basic code to exclude a file:

```
<FilesMatch "(index.php\/myadminfolder\/myurl\/myaction/someotherstuff?)$">
Satisfy Any
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from none
</FilesMatch>
```

The URL exclusion is not working.

The URL to exclude is in the form:

index.php/directory/subdirectory/action/uniqueid/blah

What is the correct URL string to add to FilesMatch to exclude any files that start with the pattern of index.php/directory/subdirectory/action - regardless of what comes after action?

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the file `index.php/directory/subdirectory/action/uniqueid/blah` does not really exist. There is probably only an `index.php` file to which you append `/directory/subdirectory/action/uniqueid/blah` as `PATH_INFO`.

Try using [Location](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location)/[LocationMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#locationmatch) instead of Files/FilesMatch.

Answer (score 0):

Like joschi said, you should use <LocationMatch></LocationMatch> instead.  Also, I don't think you need to escape /s in ...Match directives.